# Class WordCount$TokenMapper not found in Hadoop example program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working through the hadoop example found on [this page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html), and am encountering an error for Class not found. Eclipse is not seeing any syntax errors, and even highlights the class TokenizerMapper when I highlight the instance in `job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class)`. Is this because it's a subclass, or am I overlooking something here? I'm executing it from the main Hadoop node with the command `hadoop jar word.jar input output` (I already figured out that the directory (args) parameters are relative paths to /user/[myuser] in HDFS, so that's not an issue.

Any help here would be appreciated.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

    public class WordCount {

      Configuration configuration = null;

      public static class TokenizerMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
          while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
          }
        }
      }

      public static class IntSumReducer
           extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                           Context context
                           ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int sum = 0;
          for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
          }
          result.set(sum);
          context.write(key, result);
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job;
        conf.addResource(new Path("/work/hadoop/config","core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/work/hadoop/config","hdfs-site.xml"));

    try {
        job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");


        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jar name from your command line. Search for this in your document. Just besides wc.jar, it has WordCount which is your Driver class name.

```
bin/hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /user/joe/wordcount/input /user/joe/wordcount/output
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make arg[0] be WordCount, arg[1] be input and arg[2] be output, against what the code seems to expect for the I/O directories? I'm getting the error that "Output directory [stuff]/input already exists."

Comment: No it wont. see [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#jar) Directory exist meaning you might have ran the program with same input multiple times. Change your output directory everytime you are running or delete the old run's output file.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error that I'm seeing that it sees input where it's expecting output (arg[1]), so it appears that what I'm seeing goes against what the manual is saying...

Comment: Can you paste your command line that you tried. Dont manipulate please.

Comment: `hadoop jar word.jar WordCount input output`

Answer (score 0):

When your jar application entry point is your `WordCount.java`, then you can run this command without any issues. `hadoop jar word.jar input output`.Presently jar doesn't have entry point. 
so it gives error if you don't specify the fully qualified name of Class in the jar file.
By using Eclipse, You can make your class as default class/ entry point to run as follows.

```
Project=> Right click => Export => JAR File => Next => Specify Jar Path => Next 
=> JAR Manifest specification.
select the class of the application entry point.  
Main class. Browse and select the main class(WordCount in your case).
Finish.
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the JAR file to a classpath defined directory fixes the problem. You may run into "resource is out of sync with file system" error when exporting the JAR file from eclipse. In this case, simply right click on the project and select Refresh on eclipse. This will fix the 'out of sync' issue